# matlab divide sentences into words

Tags: arrays, matlab, char

Im new in matlab and ım trying to take the input from matlab gui which will be entered by a user and divide that sentence into words but I need to have them as letters because Im using a robot to write them. this letters will be send to these robots. Im using two robots and for example when I write 'lou reed' in text when ı press the button matlab function will hold this 2 words in to different char arrays so that ı can have the letters c(i) like this and send them to process. so far ı wrote these but ım stuck.

```
c = char(get(handles.edit1,'String'));
int count1;
int count2;
char word1;
char space=" ";

for i=1:length(c)
    int t = isequal(c(i),space);
    if(t==0)
        count1=count1+1;
        word1=;%ım trying to add the char here to find the new word
    else

    end
end
```

ı dont know what to do ı searched but ı couldnt find something usefull maybe ı wasnt looking right.
Anything would be helpful, thankss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What characters are allowed? First you should remove all the characters that are not allowed (substitute them with a space character?). After that just this:

```
str = '  Once   upon   a    time    ';
words_in_str = textscan(str,'%s');
words_in_str{1}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a newer version of MATLAB (greater than 2012a I think), you can use [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)

```
characterString = 'lou reed';
C = strsplit(characterString);
```

C will be a cell array with each element being a separate word.

Comment: If you have `strsplit`, this answer makes a lot more sense than doing it my way. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find the space characters in your string with

```
mystring = 'Hello Cruel World';
spaces = find(mystring==' ');
```

The variable `spaces` is now a vector pointing to where each of your word breaks are. If you want to break this up into words, you could use

```
mystring = 'Hello Cruel World';
wordboundaries = [0,find(mystring==' ')];
wordlen = diff([wordboundaries,length(mystring)+1])-1;
numwords = length(wordboundaries);
for w = 1:numwords
    idx = wordboundaries(w) + (1:wordlen(w));
    word{w} = mystring(idx);
end 
display(word);
```

Now `word` is a cell array containing the individual words.

Comment: As evidenced by the other answers, I took the most naive approach possible to this problem.  I am not used to working with strings in matlab, only numbers.  I made the mistake of thinking of the strings as numbers, and attacking the problem that way.  If I could downvote my own answer, I might do it.  :)

Comment: ım not going to do that :) but ım lost actually, strsplit @craigim is nice but ım using 2009 version and ı was looking for a simple answer like we would do it in java the thing is matlab confuses me. ı just need to know how ı can split the sentence with spaces into words and put each word into char array.

Comment: I recommend the answer given by @francesco.  It will put each word into a cell in a cell array.  The problem with putting each word in a char array is that you have to know in advance how many words you are expecting.  Or you have to create a char matrix whose width is equal to the length of the longest word.  If you really want, I can edit my code to put it in a char matrix instead of a cell array.

Comment: okey, ı will try to do it in cell array then. thanks so much, hope it works.